# iMessages being delivered to both me and my daughter

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, messages

I'm having some trouble with iTunes  We have 4 different devices connected to my iTunes account. I have one daughter's iPod, another daughters iPod, one iPad and I just got one of the girls their first phone last night and set up that phone under this same iTunes account.

All of the texts I get to my iPad are also going to her phone.  Should I have given her a totally different iTunes account?  Is there a way to give her one iMessage number and a different iMessage number on the iPad, so we don't get each other's iMessages?

Also, when I connected the new phone to this iTunes account last night, it switched the iMessage number on the iPad to the same number as the phone?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to get her a different Apple ID for iMessages to be sent separately. You can do this by one of two ways:

**Method 1: Create an Apple ID using Gmail, Outlook, etc:**

If you want to create an Apple ID, but don't want to have to restore the phone to do it, visit the [Apple ID management page](https://appleid.apple.com). **Note: your daughter will need an existing email address to do this.** Follow the onscreen instructions to create the new ID using the existing email.

**Method 2: Create an Apple ID by restoring the phone:**

If you want an email address ending in `@icloud.com`, then you have to reset the phone by navigating to `General > Reset > Reset all Content and Settings` and confirming the prompts onscreen. Then, when your phone resets, you will be able to create an Apple ID during the setup process.

**Otherwise...**

Otherwise iMessage will view as both of you as the same person.

The reason iTunes assigned the phone number to the iPad because, again, it thinks you're the same person because both devices are linked to the same Apple ID.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  Although, it does not give me the option of "create New Apple ID" when I follow these steps on the phone or the ipad.

Comment: Ok – I will edit my answer to match your situation.

Comment: I am wondering if I should just do a factory reset for the iphone that we just set up last night?  It has nothing on it yet.  Is this an option?  and then create a new itunes account for the iphone?

Comment: @Jena Yes I explain that in my answer I'm working on right now, it'll be up in just a sec

Comment: one more question..... If I do a reset on the phone, will it "delete" the sprint ringplus plan on the sprint network I just signed up for on the phone last night?  or just the content on the phone.  sorry for all the questions!

Comment: @Jena just the content, since I assume that the sprint plan is linked to the sim card.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Angelplayer! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Jena No problem

Comment: Once you've done all this, you might like to investigate [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) which will allow you all to share Apps, Books, Tunes & even a calendar, whilst preserving each user's individual accounts.